# Converting files to numpy array and saving them as csv in the same function

Tags: python, string, numpy, function, loops

I have some files in the .sgy format (which is not relevant for the question) and I want to convert them to numpy 2D arrays, and save them as .csv files in the same function.
This is the function I have written so far:

```
def segy_2_csv(directory_and_name_of_data_file):
    import numpy as np
    from obspy.io.segy.core import _read_segy

    for i in range(len(names_full[i]) -1):
        a = _read_segy(directory_and_name_of_data_file[i])
        the_array[i]   = np.array(a).transpose((1,0))
        b = np.savetxt(data_dir_CSV + names_no_format[i], the_array[i], delimiter=",")
    return b

my_data = segy_2_csv(data_dir_SGY + names_full)
```

the function runs normally. But when I run the line with the variable "my_data", I get this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

The "names_no_format" is a list of strings, each string is the name of the files. However, because I call the ith element of it (which is a string), this should work, but it does not and I have no idea why.

Comment: Do the string concatenation on another line so you're sure the error is there. Also make sure your assumptions are correct, `print(f"{type(data_dir_CSV) = }\n{data_dir_CSV = }")`, `print(f"{type(names_no_format[i]) = }\n{names_no_format[i] = }")` or `assert isinstance(names_no_format[i], str)` before `return`.

Comment: Also strange that `the_array`, `data_dir_CSV`, `names_no_format`, `names_full` are global variables, you certainly should rewrite your function.

Comment: I'm guessing  the problem is in `data_dir_CSV + names_no_format[i]`.

Comment: @paime the function runs without error, but when I use it to convert and save the files (my_data variable) I get the error. Also, why can they variables not be global variables?

Comment: @Travis_Dudeson When you call the function is when it runs, not before. So your function does not run. Maybe try what I suggested and provide the output. Regarding usage of global variables, it is bad practice / design, and it will easily get you into trouble. As is the fact that your function loads AND saves, might be good here but those are 2 tasks so it should preferably be 2 functions.

Comment: Also I just noted that the line `np.savetxt(...` is outside the for loop but its arguments do refer to the for loop variable `i`, might be unintended.

Comment: `savetxt` writes a file.  It doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Where does the error occur?  What variables are involved.  The message says you can't join a string and a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s and [paime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13636407/paime)'s comments, I figured it out.
Since the savetxt command does not return any arrays, I first converted the numpy array to pandas dataframe, and then converted it to a CSV file ([pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)). This is the code that worked:

```
## -- names of the files
names_full = os.listdir(data_dir_SGY)
for i in range (len(names_full)):
    ## -- converting to numpy array
    a       = _read_segy(data_dir_SGY + names_full[i])
    the_radargram_array   = np.array(a).transpose((1,0)) 
    
    ## -- writing numpy array as .csv
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(the_radargram_array_wo_surface))
    df.to_csv(data_dir_CSV + names_no_format[i] + ".csv", index = False)
```

This is then very easy to use later and convert any of the columns to numpy arrays by using numpy.loadtxt.